# Is there a way to hide “related videos” from the end of the You Tube video we have embedded?

Tags: html, css, video, youtube

I googled a lot and found some solution like below:

1. Adding ?rel=0 at the end of url
2. Adding css below

   .vidwrapper.ended iframe, .vidwrapper.paused iframe {
   visibility: hidden;
   }

But nothing is working. Please help

Here is my code

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoID?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Please provide your code, This will give us ease to help you. Thanks

Comment: updated post by adding my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my answer after some research.

As per my findings, previously it was possible to hide related videos by passing some parameter to the embedded YouTube url, but from 2018 disabling related video has been depreciated by Youtube.

What is in our control is:
We can restrict to show related videos only from our channel.

FYI, here are some reference links
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Revision_History

https://www.launch2success.com/youtube-no-longer-allows-you-to-turn-off-related-videos-when-embedding-a-video/